# MongoDB Client > Invalid Operation, no operations specified

Tags: javascript, mongodb, npm

**NPM Library:** `"mongodb": "3.1.4"`

I get the following error, when trying to bulk insert a list of data:

**Code:**

```
db.collection('products').insertManyAsync(products, {ordered: false})
```

**Error:**

> Invalid Operation, no operations specified

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution (but I couldn't find it listed anywhere), it turns out the `products` array was empty, which causes the error.